# Nvidia drivers installation make me unable to hibernate on ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, nvidia, swap, hibernate, acpi

I have an issue that Ive been researching since 2 months and didn't find anyone yet with that same thing. Hibernation is "important" to me because i like to let linux on a snapshooted way so that I switch to another OS and then come back to the same environment that I was working before on a dual boot machine. So I won't loose hardware resources while on the other OS (I know I could like use virtualBox...) and all applications come back. I use kde session restoring feature but not all applications support the XSM protocol.

Anyway the goal is being able to hibernate (suspend to disk) or recover from a snapshoot of the whole system in any way. Hibernation works on the ubuntu 17.10 (im not sure if i had the nvidia drivers enabled then). But still, even without the nvidia drivers, it hibernates but doesn't recover from it when I boot, which is a known issue due to the metldown kernel patch and seems to be fixable now for ubuntu.

After installing the nvidia driver 390, on all of my hibernation attempts i get stuck ad s2disk message "snapshooting system", then the fans run faster for a while and im forced to force shutdown (alt+print REISUB works too). And yes I've waited like 20 minutes on this screen.

I made a bug report here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/uswsusp/+bug/1770491
But maybe it isn't ubuntu fault. I also did this question and tried all that's there: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/667833

SPECS Dell i15-7567-A30P Gamer

```
PROCESSOR: Intel Core i7 7700HQ 7ª Gen. (até 3.8 GHz) Cache 6 MB
RAM: 16 GB DDR4 2133 MHz (suporte até 32 GB)
VIDEO CARD: Geforce GTX 1050 Ti 4 GB GDDR5
STORAGE: Drive primário SSD de 256GB + HD de 1TB (5400 RPM)
```

SWAP

```
# swapon -s
Filename                                Type            Size    Used               Priority
/dev/sda8                               partition       16726012        0       -2
```

The swap works when I fill my ram with random applications so the problem is not it. The swap partition is on the SSD drive(Should i try having it on the hdd?).

The exactly same error happens when I try either the pm-hibernate or hibernate or s2disk commands.

I would like any things or ideas I could still try or any feedback, maybe someone finds out this is a bug on nvidia drivers or i should be installing it from somewhere else or maybe its a bug on the linux kernel itself??? Also I'm open to suggestions besides all i said and the links, for hibernating.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Solved when I removed ususwp (tuxonice is too old). Using the linux default hibernation worked.